# How get specific type? T[keyof T] is combine all in one type ,

Tags: typescript

```
 const obj = {
      role  : 'admin',
      user : {
        id : 1,
        name : 'vasa',
      },
    }
```

---

```
const fun = <T>(obj: T):
      Record<`set${Capitalize<string & keyof T>}`, (a : T[keyof T]) => void>
      => {
      const action = {}
      for(const key in obj){
        action[key] = (value) => {console.log(value)}
      }
      return action
    }
    const action = fun(obj)
```

---

```
    // bug
    action.setRole({id: 2, name: 'bug'})
```

setRole receive wrong type as T[keyof T] is combine all types to one type
its supposed to be

setRole(string)

setUser(object)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```js
const obj = { role: 'admin', user: { id: 1, name: 'vasa', }, }

type Convert<Obj> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj as `set${Capitalize<Prop & string>}`]: (value: Obj[Prop]) => void
}

const capitalize = <T extends string>(str: T) =>
  `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.substr(1)}` as Capitalize<T>;

const fun = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(obj: T) =>
  (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T & string>).reduce((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [`set${capitalize(elem)}`]: (v: T[keyof T]) => { }
  }), {} as Convert<T>)

const action = fun(obj)



action.setRole('sdf') // ok
action.setUser({ id: 42, name: 'John' }) // ok
action.setUser('sdf') // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGAnEAbApgFwwDkAhgCYC2AlmCQDQwCuE%20WxmNFxAjE2DJUipAG5kIZRjAC%20TGQCgFUAJ4AHfDADC4UeygAeAPJIAfKgwKYMANoAFHGph0YAa3wqQAMxgnkEmAADNigAEnQtMjUaKDJcGgAvfAMHECcAMhhoLDoAc1MZQIBdYgAKcVxmET97RyKASlRzURBuBUUFUEhYYCiYuMTNNAMAFRh8AA8ofDAKCCyoHLB80uziEcaUUysg8OybAAYigDooEABVNQ0sSLZS%20pk9xeOIZnhs0t4HwJgAyOjYvEkqNTABuJRdaAwLzMMAWUbjKYzOYwABK%20FAWAoBmyeSYsNcYBAAHcwKZTKUEIh1ptttZSn4MVBju4VBBKUhGgEAIJYLBkFQGVneGBjTK45amerHLD4CjMYD4UqlMjAYBMfAEKi0mCldA7azHI2q9UG2zBfBhdC9AEDJKlTX4bWFEq60TrGzCnwjBpNDCyHYyepMdAyX7zHRgPRYQwjKUQ8BQ1VQGjgCwwsAcxD1JRKZOpsAvS2ovBKkgQCheEiNAD0NbgrgU%20fARag5zYWD1zh4MAALAAmARCEQkABSIAAFvRZLX6yBG83CyF2%20xSuXK9WYHXxnyQFggA)

This approach `Record<"set${Capitalize<string & keyof T>}", (a : T[keyof T]) => void>` is not safe because key and value of the Record are union of all allowed keys, whereas you need to map each key to each specific value. This is exactly what I did in `Convert`.

`Convert` - iterates throught object keys, renames each key (adds `set` prefix) and assigns `(value: Obj[Prop]) => void` to appropriate key.

Please see docs for [key remmaping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!!!!
Your solution accurately solves the problem!!

Unfortunately I'm new in typescript world,
this is a level of programming that my brain currently cannot process. :)

I can not convert your solution to the bigger problem that is trying to solve,
I will try to build a more complex example closer to the real problem which I came across

Comment: SUre, please provide your bigger example

Comment: After thinking I realized the magic of Convert<T> and it solved all my problems!!!!!
You are a genius...

Comment: @Vasa added a bit more explanation with appropriate link to docs

Comment: @Vasa if this answer is helpful you can either accept it or upvote, or both