# Generic function to map object property name

Tags: typescript

I want to create a generic map function that takes any type object as first argument and one prefix string as second argument that will be concatenated to object's property name with same value and returns this new created object.

Answer (score 2):

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962981/how-get-specific-type-tkeyof-t-is-combine-all-in-one-type/69963066#69963066)

Consider this exmaple:

```js
type Remap<Obj, Prefix extends string> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj as `${Prefix}${Prop & string}`]: Obj[Prop]

}
const map = <Obj, Prefix extends string>(obj: Obj, prefix: Prefix) =>
  (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof Obj & string>).reduce((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [`${prefix}${elem}`]: obj[elem]
  }), {} as Remap<Obj, Prefix>)

const result = map({
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}, 'set_')

result.set_one //
result.set_two
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBASlAtgQwgHgPICMBWAaGABQCcoAzASwA8YoqQoA7AEwGcZWRiLGBzAPhgBeGAG9gMGAG0SAewgweMANZQwssjGw4YydgAMAJKJLlqAX2NyFAMg5cevc-oC6ALi24ZxeS%20DBzYABjWUZOGBQFEUxcAlNKGjoGFnZObj5%20AApZXA9tAghSBI946gBKYX4JGEztKCCQADpVMFZs3Aq9GABBYmJkMDQWjU8dOzTHfjLG0mYAVyCoTMzkIKCCKAAbJAqhQUzxSUlGk9X16skpI1FCsypLUS2kZ3cYHJwpJ8Q-SXMyglE5l07AQkRi%20CIRWoU38ITCIBgpFYc02CJEkQO1VCUA8AEY8NUQAB3WQeABMBMkIAAFqQcTAAMwBAgAclYUBAAH0WWV-EiUU12VzsTAAPSi4D81GNIWc4myYBAA)

See [key-remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)

I have used `as` type asserion because this is the only way to `go` in this particular case

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help.